# Horizontally organised dynamic grid with CSS and jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, image, lazy-loading

The title could be a bit misleading, but could not find a more fitting title.

I'm intensively working with images on a website and loading more than 50 of them really slows things down. I wanted to use Lazyload to delay the load of images not yet in the view port, however, the layout does not make this possible.

I have the images right after each other: `<div id="container"><img ..><img ..><img ..></div>`and I use CSS to organise them into separate columns. (To be absolutely correct, the images are in divs as well: `<div class="pin"><img ..></div>`

Here's my CSS for the thing.

```
#container {
  width:100%;
  padding:2px 2px 2px 2px;

  column-count:7;
  -webkit-column-count:7;
  -moz-column-count:7;
  -ms-column-count:7;
  -o-column-count:7;

  column-gap:2px;
  -webkit-column-gap:2px;
  -moz-column-gap:2px;
  -ms-column-gap:2px;
  -o-column-gap:2px;

  column-fill:balance;
  -webkit-column-fill:balance;
  -moz-column-fill:balance;
  -ms-column-fill:balance;
  -o-column-fill:balance;
}

.pin {
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  column-break-inside:avoid;
  -webkit-column-break-inside:avoid;
  -moz-column-break-inside:avoid;
  -ms-column-break-inside:avoid;
  -o-column-break-inside:avoid;
}
```

My issue is, that this way the top-left pin is the first pin inside the container and the next pin is under it, not next to it. So the Lazyload script will load the first as first, and then the one under it, while the first pin of the second column does not get loaded.. Not until I scroll down to the bottom of the container, let all the pins in the first column load and only then start loading the pins in the second column.
There is an option in Lazylaod to load things in a specific container, however, if I'd like to have a 100 pins inside my container (from which, many will be outside the view port), Lazylaod will load them at the same time... This option was designed for smaller containers.

My question is: (first) is there a way to organise my pins with CSS so that the second pin is not under the first in first column, but it is the top most in the second column? If not, does anyone have any suggestion on how to solve this dilemma?

(Mainly, Im interested in conceptual ideas first and not some other, ready-to-use grid script.. Only if there is no other way I'd use another script, since that case I have a lot to redo..)

Thanks!

Comment: I was thinking, with jQuery I could position my pins, but I'd love to stick to some simple CSS work... :)

Comment: Do your container divs have backgrounds/ borders/ w/e, in other words, does the visitor see the columns or a grid? If your img thumbs are all same height: you could simply organize them in rows with CSS. If columns are necessary, maybe you could dynamically add the img src""'s with js, the first ones first? As for your first question.. I don't think there's a way other than to position the images absolutely, but correct me if I'm wrong...

Comment: @Tyblitz Thanks for the second part a lot! At least I can stop "looking" for an alternative. I don't think however, that I correctly understood the first part.. The images are different height. They are photographs..

Comment: Yeah, just what I thought, a bit like pinterest (well,, you called the divs 'pins' lol). Nope then rows won't work either.. Perhaps a JS/ AJAX pro knows more about this than me. Good luck!